# htaccess rewrite rules are not working with urls that end with .cfm

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, railo

I'm working on fixing all my URL's to be shorter with 301 redirects. I have fix almost all of them, however there is a url that is ending with .cfm that will not rewrite.

```
FROM: http://www.mydomain.com/index.cfm/catlink/17/pagelink/7/sublink/34/art/41/rec/1/page.cfm

TO: http://www.mydomain.com/story/resources/health/page/168/page.html
```

If I change `/page.cfm` to `/page.html` then the rewrite will work.

Here is the rewrite rule that works for my other urls

```
RewriteRule ^index.cfm/catlink/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)([/])pagelink/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)([/])sublink/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)([/])art/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)(.*)$ 

http://localhost/index.cfm?page=moved&cat=$3&subcat=$5&article=$7&story=$8 [R=301]
```

Why does it work when the URL ends with .html but not when it ends with .cfm? What am I doing wrong?

This is current link and will not work:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.cfm/catlink/17/pagelink/7/sublink/34/art/41/rec/1/page.cfm
```

If I manually change the end of it to .html, I can get it to work:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.cfm/catlink/17/pagelink/7/sublink/34/art/41/rec/1/page.html
```

Comment: Show the two links you are trying. That is what `html` link passes and what `cfm` link fails.

Comment: I have added how I can change the link to make it work.  Just look at the end of the urls.

Comment: Your regex is rather loose. I think that's your root cause. Is everything you are capturing digits?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I guess I am. When I first started learning rewrites this worked so I haven't taken time to learn how to optimize it. I'm guess I'm going to be forced to learn more about this.

Comment: Can you give the full .htaccess file? Are there any other rewrite rules?

Comment: I worked with this person(co worker of mine) and ruled out the rule itself. The rule works if the end of the url is `.html`, and not if it is `.cfm`. I even simplified the rule down to `^index.cfm/catlink` being re-written to `index.cfm`. It worked for .html ending urls but not `.cfm` ending urls. I think the problem is going to have something to do with the way apache and railo are installed.

Comment: To respond to Toby, I tested this issue, by making an htaccess file with no other rewrites but this one and the same issue happens.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Apache httpd is passing it off to Tomcat before Apache looks at the .htaccess. To test this, move your rewrite rules into your vhost. If they work, then that's what the problem was.

Comment: Yes, we have narrowed it down to this being the issue. Is there another way to accomplish this without modifying the server files for every rewrite?

Comment: Jordan Michael in the Railo community is working on a native connector called mod_cfml - he takes this into account I believe - Stay tuned on the Railo mailing list. Otherwise, I'm not really sure how you get around this as it's a mod_jk / ajp / timing issue in apache.

Answer (score 0):

First off, change your the first part of your RewriteRule to be the following, more concise expression:

```
^index.cfm/catlink/(\d+)/pagelink/(\d+)/sublink/(\d+)/art/(\d+)/(.*)$
```

I believe that alone might resolve the issue. However, if it does not, and you *don't care* about the rest of the URL, try the following:

```
^index.cfm/catlink/(\d+)/pagelink/(\d+)/sublink/(\d+)/art/(\d+)/
```

**Note:** this removes the anchor (`$`) and therefore allows the URL to be open ended.

Comment: your rewrite does work well if the requested url ends in anything but `.cfm`, which I don't think has anything to do with this rule.

Comment: @Kevin B, as you noted this must be caused by something else. The rule I provided *should* work.