# adding index.cfm to url seems to ignore .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, coldfusion, railo

I'm trying to disallow access to certain folders in my webApp, but there seems to be some exception to the use of index.cfm somewhere...

for this example I'm using just the folllowing mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.cfm [QSA,L]
```

accessing the following urls with results:

```
/index.cfm //->/index.cfm naturally
/test/test.html //->/index.cfm 
/test/ //->/index.cfm 
/test/test.cfm //->/index.cfm 
/test/index.cfm //->/test/index.cfm
```

Note that the last request seems to ignore the rewrite rule, how could that happen?

(All files above are not present in the file system with exception to the index.cfm in the root)

**EDIT** also, the .htaccess file is placed in the root directory

**EDIT 2** I added a `RewriteLog` to see whats going on, There definitely is a difference but I dont see why...

**/test/index.html**

```
[rid#15d1048/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /test/index.html
[rid#15d1048/initial] (1) pass through /test/index.html
[rid#15d1048/initial] (3) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] add path info postfix: C:/my/local/dir/test -> C:/my/local/dir/test/index.html
[rid#15d1048/initial] (3) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/my/local/dir/test/index.html -> test/index.html
[rid#15d1048/initial] (3) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'test/index.html'
[rid#15d1048/initial] (2) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] rewrite 'test/index.html' -> 'index.cfm'
[rid#15d1048/initial] (3) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] add per-dir prefix: index.cfm -> C:/my/local/dir/index.cfm
[rid#15d1048/initial] (2) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] strip document_root prefix: C:/my/local/dir/index.cfm -> /index.cfm
[rid#15d1048/initial] (1) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] internal redirect with /index.cfm [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#15cb4c0/initial/redir#1] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.cfm
[rid#15cb4c0/initial/redir#1] (1) pass through /index.cfm
[rid#15cb4c0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/my/local/dir/index.cfm -> index.cfm
[rid#15cb4c0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.cfm'
[rid#15cb4c0/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] rewrite 'index.cfm' -> 'index.cfm'
[rid#15cb4c0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] add per-dir prefix: index.cfm -> C:/my/local/dir/index.cfm
[rid#15cb4c0/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: C:/my/local/dir/index.cfm [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

**/test/index.cfm**

```
[rid#15ca1a0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /test/index.cfm
[rid#15ca1a0/initial] (1) pass through /test/index.cfm
[rid#15ca1a0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] add path info postfix: C:/my/local/dir/test -> C:/my/local/dir/test/index.cfm
[rid#15ca1a0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/my/local/dir/test/index.cfm -> test/index.cfm
[rid#15ca1a0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'test/index.cfm'
[rid#15ca1a0/initial] (2) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] rewrite 'test/index.cfm' -> 'index.cfm'
[rid#15ca1a0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] add per-dir prefix: index.cfm -> C:/my/local/dir/index.cfm
[rid#15ca1a0/initial] (2) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] strip document_root prefix: C:/my/local/dir/index.cfm -> /index.cfm
[rid#15ca1a0/initial] (1) [perdir C:/my/local/dir/] internal redirect with /index.cfm [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Comment: Is your rule only `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.cfm [QSA,L]`, no previous rules or conditions?

Comment: @JonLin in my testcase it is yes

Comment: My co-worker and I came across the same issue several months ago, we still haven't come to a solution for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949746/htaccess-rewrite-rules-are-not-working-with-urls-that-end-with-cfm The upvoted answer explains why it is happening, but as far as I know, there still isn't a solution. Basically, the request gets handed off to railo before apache processes .htaccess files.

Comment: Our current work-around is to use the missingTemplateHandler for this purpose.

Comment: What connector are you using? mod_proxy or mod_jk?

Comment: @Jordan neither, I'm using `mod_caucho`, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @KevinB hmm that could work yes, I was hoping for a mod_rewrite solution though :(

Comment: I've never used mod_coucho, but yes, that's what I was asking about. mod_jk is very aggressive when it comes to "claiming" requests that are mapped for it. I wonder if mod_coucho is the same way? Perhaps try mod_proxy instead and see if you get less-aggressive behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the perfect answer i was looking for but this is what I did to get the same result:

In the `.htaccess` I add the following line to forward any files not processed by railo:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(my|forbidden|folders)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.cfm/some/page [L]
```

In the `application.cfc` I add the following line to forward the files processed by railo:

```
<cfif Find(listFirst(arguments.targetPage, "/"), "my,forbidden,folders")>
    <cfset GetPageContext().Forward("/index.cfm/some/page")>
</cfif>
```

This way I can show another page whilst not changing the requested url.

I was hoping for a solution just in the `.htaccess` but it seems because of a bug in the resin / apache connection this cannot work yet.